# Certain time to wait for socket connection

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, server

I tried to made a script that connects to a server with *python-socket.

```
# connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# in this case socket.socket() is more clearer 
connection = socket.socket()
connection.connect((ip, port))
```

But when the ip or the port are incorrect, it tries to connect forever.
So how can you implement a certain time to wait for a server to respond/connect? For example when the server isn't reachable after 5 seconds, the connection will be closed with an error that the server is unreachable/offline.

Comment: Even without `settimeout`, `connect` fails within a 2-3 seconds if the IP exists but the port doesn't (ConnectionRefusedError) and in about 20 seconds (TimeoutError) if the IP doesn't exist, at least on my Windows system.  How long did you wait?

Comment: About 10 secounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a specific time to wait for the server you can simply do this:

```
connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.settimeout(5)  # waits 5 sec until the connection will be closed
connection.connect((ip, port))
connection.settimeout(None)  #sets the timeout to None (important)
```

In this example, the connection will wait for 5 seconds until it raises an exception, because the time is over. You can simply catch this exception in a try statement with "except socket.timeout:"